# how to change the color of disabled controls

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, jquery, css

Q:

I wanna to change the color of any disabled control to black like in enabled one because of special case, i tried many solutions like make the textbox read only but (i donot want this solution because of some reason of this case) , i use Css file , every thing is changed except the color of the text how to change the color to be more clear please.

EDIT:: tested against IE

My CSS:

`input[disabled] { border:solid 1px red; background-color:White;color:red !important;font-weight:bold;font-size:medium; }`

My .aspx sample::


    `<title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Enabled ="false"
         ></asp:TextBox>

</div>
</form>
```

`

Comment: have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602070/changing-font-colour-in-textboxes-in-ie-which-are-disabled

Comment: i read it ,,, the answer talk about a Jquery lib i want it,or the steps to use it ,, thanks alot

Comment: IE won't let you change the color of disabled textbox, it's in its very core. But don't give up, I'm sure that at some point even IE (maybe 9, maybe 10) will let web developers change disabled textbox color. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following CSS2 selector:

```
input[disabled=disabled] {
 /* your style */
 color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: yeah i use this style ,, it enable me to change every thing except the color of the text..

Comment: Hmmm, can you post the offending html snippet and css then please

Comment: i use it with <asp:TextBox runat ="server" Enabled = "false">

Comment: The actual HTML would be more helpful just to make sure that .net isn't inserting any extra inline styling code.

Comment: i edit my question,,ind write my code it works only on firefox.