# How to make dropdown list unselectable?

Tags: javascript, css, jsf

How can I make the `<h:selectOneMenu>` dropdown list unselectable?

It is not like using `disabled`. I just want to make the dropdown list options unselectable and to appear with a different (inactive) style class.

How can I achieve this? By a JSF component attribute or CSS or JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean with "unchangeable/unselectable"? That nothing happens when clicking on it (no drop down) or that selecting a value doesn't let it show up, or that it has no effect when submitting?

Comment: @Mulmoth "unchangeable/unselectable" mean that nothing happens when clicking on it (no drop down).

Comment: Then the disabled attribute is the only option.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlName" runat="server" style="pointer-events: none; cursor: default;">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Add `style` attribute to `DropDownList` as `style="pointer-events: none; cursor: default;"`. This will work succesfully, I have tried this.

Comment: with jQuery: 
$('#DropdownID').css({"pointer-events": "none", "cursor": "default"});

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, all you need to do is use the `disabled` attribute.

So, if you have a select tag like this:

```
<select>
  <option>Value</option>
  <option>Value</option>
  <option>Value</option>
</select>
```

Simply change it to this:

```
<select disabled>
  <option>Value</option>
  <option>Value</option>
  <option>Value</option>
</select>
```

Some doctypes require all attributes to have values, in order to be valid. In that case, you can just use `disabled="true"` instead.

Comment: If the doctype requires a value, shouldn't it be `disabled="disabled"` instead?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/602298/620338), some browsers allow to change the style of disabled components (non-IE), some not (IE). However, the answer is 3 years old - a long time for browsers. So you could try a solution like:

```
<h:selectOneMenu disabled="true" style="..." ...>
```

... and check the result with different browsers.

Or alternatively use the `readonly` attribute:

```
<h:selectOneMenu readonly="true" style="..." ...>
```