# Change color of value in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, colors

```html
<input class="problem" type="text" value="some text" disabled="disabled">
```

How can i change color of "some text"?

upd: Styling by CSS working only in Chrome & Mozilla. I need support of all browser including IE7+

Comment: using CSS is simle: `color:#ff0000;` will be red

Comment: Checkout the style="color:green" or any color would work in all browsers

Comment: Just add style, as show in the answers. Only one problem though, Opera doesn't color it when disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cross-browser solution, you need to use `readonly` and `unselectable` attributes instead of `disabled`, and apply these styles:

```
.problem[readonly]{
     color: red;
     /*Preventing selection*/
     -webkit-touch-callout: none;
     -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
     /**/
}​
```

*markup*:

```
<input class="problem" type="text" value="some text" readonly unselectable="on">
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UKukL/)

Comment: @Godban I have slightly improved my answer. Look again.

Answer (score 3):

just apply some css style, e.g.

```
.problem {
  color : red;
}
```

you can even define two different colours for both normal and disabled inputs like so;

```
.problem { color : red; }
.problem[disabled] { color : #cfcfcf; }
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dgNZS

On older IE versions is not possible change the colour of a disabled input element as already [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602070/changing-font-colour-in-textboxes-in-ie-which-are-disabled) but you can try to follow bobince's workaround.

Comment: I'll just delete disabled="disabled". Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can change the disable style of the textbox for all properties in all browsers, except the color of the text and only in the IE.
For IE (for all properties except the text color) you must set the **doctype** to 4.01 strict, and then
using the code like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
input[disabled], input[readonly] { 
 background-color: green; 
 border: #3532ff 1px solid; 
 color: #00FF00;
 cursor: default; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input class="problem" type="text" value="some text" disabled="disabled">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But if you use the **readonly** instead of **disabled="disabled"** like *Engineer* wrote this works also in the ie.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a Style ie `style="color:green"`

```
<input class="problem" type="text" value="some text" disabled="disabled" style="color:green">
```

Or Include this in your class you give to input.

Answer (score 0):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/ELuXW/1/

API: CSS - http://api.jquery.com/css/

This should help, `:)`

**code**

```
$('.problem').css('color', 'blue');​
```