# Can I change the color of Disabled HTML Select Element in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement of changing the color of a html select. I have search a lot but was not find a sample that works in IE. So, can I change the color of Disabled HTML Select Element in IE? I need a sample, in css or javascript or in jquery.
Here is what I have tried.

```
<select disabled="disabled">
    <option value="a">option A</option>
    <option value="b">option B</option>
    <option value="c">option C</option>
</select>

[disabled] {
  color: #933;
  background-color: #ffc;
}


select:disabled
{
    border: solid 1px silver;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    color:blue;
}


[disabled] option {
    background-color: #ffc;  color: #933;
}
```

Comment: use another element to display instead of select( hide the select when disabled).  `I  need code` is not a question and you would need to provide code that changes select currently

Comment: @charlietfl, it look like a good suggestion? I will try. Edited Question

Comment: What color do you want to change? Each of those selects is targeting different things. Also, what IE do you want this to work in? Just IE9+, or deeper support?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/602298/1113426) could be interesting for you.

Comment: @Engineer Link that only contains word 'this' is one of the worst possible.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov You have your own opinion about 'that'.And that's fine, man!

Comment: @Engineer UX SE has [good question on the subject](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12100/why-shouldnt-we-use-words-such-as-here-and-this-in-textlinks).

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to use the `::-ms-value` selector:

```
select[disabled]::-ms-value {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
[disabled="disabled"] {
    color: #933;
    background-color: #ffc;
}
```

or

```
*[disabled="disabled"] {
    color: #933;
    background-color: #ffc;
}
```

or

```
select[disabled="disabled"] {
    color: #933;
    background-color: #ffc;
}
```

or with jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('[disabled="disabled"]').css({ 'color': '#993333', 'background-color': '#ffffcc' });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: best way is to give your select box an id-attribute or class-name select it via css like this select.name {...} because selecting by using the attribute is a thing the IE is not able to do in earlier versions.

Comment: The problem is not the css selector. IE just can't use any color other than gray for disabled select options.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, none of the above/below answers worked for me, but this did:

```
# Select all disabled DOM objects
$(':disabled').css({
    color:'red'
});

# Select disabled DOM objects by HTML tag <input>
$('input:disabled').css({
    color:'red'
});
```

For more information: https://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/