# how to get text in disabled option to change color in IE9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

In all major browsers except IE9, it colors a disabled option's text to red this code:

```
<option disabled='disabled' class='red' value=''>No Students available to take up Assessment</option>

...
//CSS
.red{
color:red;
}
```

But in IE, it does not changed text color, it keeps it a grey disabled color. How can I get the disabled color to change in IE9?

Comment: i have found out it can't be done by just css, need a workaround in javascript for IE9 as well

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select :disabled.red {
    color: red;
}
```

Here's a [document about the `:disabled` pseudo-class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127307%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from Microsoft.

Here's a [fiddle that should work in IE9 and up](http://jsfiddle.net/H5u6n/3/).

---

**Update:** This seems to work only in IE>8. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/602298/2005939) points out the workaround of using the readonly attribute on form elements. That's not an option for the option tag though.

There are JavaScript workaround for old IEs around. A simple Google search led me to [this site](http://harrybailey.com/2008/11/disabling-select-options-in-internet-explorer/) which provides a jQuery solution.

**From [the blog](http://harrybailey.com/2008/11/disabling-select-options-in-internet-explorer/):**

> By adding a little css styling magic and you end up with an identical
>   outcome in all other modern browsers.
>
> You can then enable and disable using javascript. Many people have
>   written code which makes an option look like it’s disabled, waits for
>   a click on the option element and then bluring it or focusing the next
>   / previously selected option to make it act like it’s disabled.
>
> I have come up with functions used with jQuery to disable / enable a
>   select option by converting it to an optgroup and back. It is tested
>   in firefox 2 & 3, safari 3, ie 6 + 7, and it works in Opera 9
>   (although the opgroups jump to the bottom)

Comment: I tried `.red:disabled{color:red;}`, but did not work, reason I can't use `option:disabled {
    color: red;
}` is because I don't want all disabled options to be red

Comment: @user1723760 I've updated the code to only color .red options

Comment: I tried you updated code but still no color change. Even in the fiddle it shows no change in color.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps use the attribute selector in CSS?

```
option:disabled,
option[disabled] {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I don't want all disabled options to be red so I will try your code but replace option with .red

Comment: Ok then, code updated. But the part I was trying to point out is still the same.  use `[disabled]` instead of `:disabled`

Comment: The .red[disabled] and the option[disabled] both did not work

Comment: @ChrisBarr I actually tried using the [disabled] rule, and for some reason the only way of selecting a disabled option using IE is via the :disabled pseudo-class.

Comment: Really? That's odd. I guess it might be worth using both in the same rule as a catch-all in that case. Updating answer again.