# Cant change the color of the disabled textfield

Tags: html

I have a textbox in my function which I have disabled with `field.disabled=true`.

Now I want the color in black instead of grey

I have written a function, inside the function I have disabled the field and by default it's in the color grey, I want that color as black `field.disabled = true`

I have tried, `field.style.color="black"`; but that did not seem to work.

I have tried `field.style.color="black";` this also doesn't seem to work.

I have received the value in a variable(field) and I have disabled the text box value. My problem is that it is looking properly, so I need that color as black.

Comment: which browser you using?

Comment: which color text color or background color

Answer (score 0):

use readonly instead of disabled then style them as you want. Check here for more info [Changing font colour in Textboxes in IE which are disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602070/changing-font-colour-in-textboxes-in-ie-which-are-disabled/602298#602298)

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows

```
<style type="text/css">
.disableinputColor
{
    color:black;
}
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function changeColor()
    {
        var el = document.getElementById('YourDisabledTextId');
        el.className = "disableinputColor";
    }
</script>
```

I think you disabled the textbox using javascript (dynamically) so better to change color of textbox from javascript
Hope it Helps..