# Font colour of Disabled Textbox with Read only property false

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net

I have a `textbox` which is `disabled` and `Readonly` false with HAND SYMBOL onclick.

How can I change the font `colour` of that `textbox`.

Thanks

EDIT: Text box and style shown below

```
<style>
.txtclass{cursor:pointer;}
</style>

  <asp:TextBox ID="txt" CssClass="txtclass" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval  (Container.DataItem, "LicenseID") %>' Enabled="False" BackColor="#DCE4FA" Width="220px" ReadOnly="True" BorderStyle="None" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#993333"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: css styling.. or foregroundcolor property

Comment: there are number of options to do this... please let us know how you are disabling the textbox.. ? is it disabling on any condition in c# or you are disabling this by jquery or javascript??? so that we can help you in right direction

Comment: Textbox is disabled in server side not through javascript function. Browser is IE 9

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css

```
input[type="text"][disabled] {
   color: red;
}
```

Here is a similar question on SO
[Changing font colour in Textboxes in IE which are disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602070/changing-font-colour-in-textboxes-in-ie-which-are-disabled/602298#602298)